# What is the best dictionary for software development terminology?

Tags: terminology

On stack overflow, I see that there is referred to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/) *a lot*. However, I'm often not sure whether they are the definite authority for very specific software development related concepts. For example, I have recently looked for definitions of the terms [web server/service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205788/is-there-a-difference-between-a-web-server-and-a-web-service) and [RPC/IPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161674/is-there-a-difference-between-rpc-and-ipc), and the responses I get very often refer to Wikipedia (directly and indirectly).

Hence my question: which sources do you trust the most for definitions of software development jargon?

Answer (score 4):

http://www.google.com

And no, this isn't being tongue-in-cheek.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I used to trust Wikipedia, and I still read it to get an idea about the subject. But definitely books are better choice. Because they not only have a "compressed" explanation but also provide an examples and give broader description. As professors of my university say, don't trust wikipedia, search for an authorized source. For example a huge information about web service technology you can find in the book Building Web Services with Java - Making Sense of XML, SOAP, WSDL, UDDI - 2nd Edition 2005. It contains information you'll never find in Wikipedia or even in Google (Unless you'll find this book using it ;) ).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Wikipedia is usually trustworthy about technical matters.  It also has the virtues of being readily accessible and can be more up to date than books.  For example, I'd have to go and get the book you recommend on web services, and if some neat new thing appeared as much as four years ago it wouldn't be in that book.

Comment: Compare brief description with thorough explanation of a subject. The question is which one you choose. Of course there's no point in buying books about jQuery API. I think its already fully described here. But stuff like network security, grid computing, soa technologies, etc, you need a deep understanding of the subject, which cannot be provided by wikipedia. Wiki just shows you the direction.

Answer (score 1):

Google and technical & non-technical software development books.

Answer (score 1):

"[A Story Culture](http://www.randsinrepose.com/archives/2010/02/08/a_story_culture.html)" may be a useful read for you as you want something other than a dictionary, IMO.  You want something with the knowledge and wisdom of the topic rather than simply what does this mean.  For example, there are a couple of blog posts about Technical Debt that I really like to use for reference about the subject, one from [Steve McConnell](http://forums.construx.com/blogs/stevemcc/archive/2007/11/01/technical-debt-2.aspx) and one from [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TechnicalDebt.html).

While I can generally suggest going to the source for the term, there is something to be said for a term getting overloaded or overused so that it can have little meaning.  There are a few folks' blogs that I can say I trust to get some understanding on a subject including [Joels](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/) and [Jeffs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/), but don't forget that each of us has a brain and we shouldn't be afraid to use it.